# Mongo pagination

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pagination, morphia

I have a use case where I need to get list of Objects from mongo based off a query. But, to improve performance I am adding Pagination. 
So, for first call I get list of say 10 Objects, in next I need 10 more. But I cannot use offset and pageSize directly because the first 10 objects displayed on the page may have been modified [ deleted ].

Solution is to find Object Id of last object passed and retrieve next 10 objects after that ObjectId.

Please help how to efficiently do it using Morphia mongo.

Comment: Wouldn't you instead just omit where `deleted = 1` ?

Comment: Yes sure. but if I load next 10 objects, object 11th will be lost for user to view. Wont it?

Comment: It depends on how often you expect the documents to move. Are you just over killing by dong this or is there really gonna be a detrimental effect to the user by not doing this?

Comment: Consider it as a list of My Item collection. Which is subjected to change. I can delete frequently while being on Page 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using morphia you can do this by the following command.

```
datastore.find(YourClass.class).field(id).smallerThan(lastId).limit(10).order("-ts");
```

Since you are querying for retrieving the items after the last retrieved id, you won't be bothered to deal with deleted items.

Comment: You should probably add a ``sort(field)``, otherwise the order of values isn't guaranteed

Comment: Do you mean sort based on Object id?

Comment: @cubbuk: are you assuming, Object ID is sorted? I am not sure if mongo Object ( auto generated ) are sorted.

Comment: Well one way could be add tstamp to your records and sort according to that. You can use the timestamp of the objectId itself. This way you will ensure that items will be retrieved in insert order. Or even better just use an id which is omni-increasing.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I have thought up of is that you will have the same problem as with using `skip()` here unless you intend to change how your interface works.

Using ranged queries like this demands that you use a different kind of interface since it is must harder to detect now exactly what page you are on and how many pages exist in the future, especially if you are doing this to avoid problems with conventional paging.

The default type of interface to arise from this type of paging is merely a infinitely scrolling page, think of YouTube video comments or Facebook wall feed or even Google+. There is no physical pagination or "pages", instead you have a get more button.

This is the type of interface you will need to use to get ranged paging working better.

As for the query @cubbuk gives a good example:

```
datastore.find(YourClass.class).field(id).smallerThan(lastId).limit(10).order("-ts");
```

Except it should be `greaterThan(lastId)` since you want to find everything above that last `_id`. I would also sort by `_id` unless you make your OjbectIds sometime before you insert a record, if this is the case then you can use a specific timestamp set on insert instead.